# indexedDB add record to objectStore only works once

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am trying to understand how indexedDB works and wrote a rather basic site visitor tracker. This works the first time around. When page is loaded the first time everything works as expected. I can see the data is added into my objectStore.

Now every time I refresh the page I do not get another record added as expected. What am I not doing correctly ? Any guidance or help is most welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other 
  head content must come *after* these tags -->

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net
  /javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
  // UI here
</body>
<script>
  var timeDate = new Date();
  var tD=timeDate.toString();
  alert(timeDate);          

  var ip = geoplugin_request();           // get client ip
  alert(ip);

  var city = geoplugin_city();            // get client city
  alert(city);

  var country = geoplugin_countryName() ; // get client country
  alert(country);

  var os = navigator.oscpu;               // get platform info
  alert(os);

  window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || 
  window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

  //prefixes of window.IDB objects
  window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || 
  window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
  window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || 
  window.msIDBKeyRange

  if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB.")
  }

  var visitorInfo = [{ 
         date   : tD, 
         ip     : ip, 
         city   : city, 
         country: country,
         os     :os },            
     ];

     var db;
     var request = window.indexedDB.open("visitor", 1);

     request.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("error: ");
     };

     request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        db = request.result;
        console.log("success: "+ db);
     };

     request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;

        if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains("userinfo")){
            console.log("creating userinfo table..");
            //var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("userinfo", {keyPath: "ip",autoIncrement:true});            
            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("userinfo", {keyPath: "ip"});            
        }
        else{
            console.log("userinfo exists");
            }

        for (var i in visitorInfo) {
           objectStore.add(visitorInfo[i]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Working directly with indexedDb API is tedious. Might consider using a wrapper library that simplifies configuration, setting indexes and crud operations. MDN docs has some suggestions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: Thank you I am aware of wrappers like dexie.js but I want to truly 'understand' how to do things using the indexedDB API itself hence the struggle with the site tracker. Wrappers are all well and good but one does not have the control one gets with using the API directly.

Comment: I don't see where you add anything except in `onupgradeneeded `

Comment: This is where I need help. onupgradeneeded works like expected for the first time. I am trying to figure out how to make it add records after that first time.

Comment: You would just add inside pageload code after you configure database. `upgrade needed ` would only fire when you change version allowing you to modify existing db structure

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the code in your question

Comment: Dumb question but since indexedDb is only local to user's browser what is point of setting up a user database there? Will only ever get data from current user

Comment: @charlietfl there is no such thing as a dumb question in my world only either the lack of required knowledge or a level of comfort necessary with a code base or tool to implement whatever it is I may be trying to put together:-) and I believe under the hood pouchDB uses indexedDB so once I get this working, replicating and syncing will be done by pouchDB or CouchDB.

Comment: Ok in that case should start off using pouchDb then. It does a lot more than create simple db tables in order to manage all the synchronization. It creates numerous sub tables to track revisions for example in order to know what to synchronize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that inserts objects is located within the onupgradeneeded handler. The onupgradeneeded handler function only runs when the database is first created or the version is incremented.

On the other hand, the success handler for the indexedDB.open call runs every time, both when the database is created, upgraded, or just opened.

Therefore, you want to move the code that inserts objects from the onupgradeneeded handler into the success handler.

Answer (score 1):

I have run access to the same problem. Two things were causing that in my case.

1. Use onsuccess handler if you have already created the table/indexdb.
2. This one is the silly part but I've made this mistake. If you are reviewing the data over browser developer tools, the indexDB itself doesn't update the records when you click on the odjectstore/table. You have to click on refresh button on indexdb window under application section to see if the record has been created. The refresh button is the left corner of the dataset.